# how to solve this algorithm question (about plane and lines)?

Tags: algorithm

There was a question "Given a number of lines with format Ax + By + C = 0 and then compute how many areas in the plane that these lines can divide into. I didn't have any idea about this question. Can anyone help me to solve the question?

Answer (score 0):

The maximum number of areas that a plane can be divided into by `n` lines is:

```
A(n) = ((n * n) + n + 2) / 2
```

See [this explenation](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/proofs/LinesDividePlane.shtml) for reference.

But there are still **3 special cases** left:

1. The lines have to be different from every other line
2. Parallel lines will lead to less areas because of less crossing points of lines
3. Every point in which more than two lines cross will lead to less areas

So a solution in pseudo code could be:

```
function calculate_areas():
    L = all lines
    L' = remove_duplicate_lines(L)
    
    n = number of lines in L'

    p = number_of_parallel_lines(L') # note that three lines that are parallel to each other are counted as +2 here
    c = number_of_crosspoints_of_more_than_two_lines(L') # for each crossing point add the number of lines that cross in this point - 2

    a = (((n * n) + n + 2) / 2) - p - c

    return a
```